# Select div children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select the child of a div using jquery. I try with children() but didn't work

```
<div class="main" id="this_456" onclick="change(456)">

 <div id="title">some text</div>

 <div id="body">some text as well</div>

</div>
```

javascript

```
function change(id)
{
$('#this_'+id).children("#body").fadeOut();

}
```

Comment: Did you try $('#this_'+id+' #body').fadeOut(); Well, it will work only if you know the child id so you can simplify it using $('#body').fadeOut();

Comment: I have a suspicion that you have several of this structure, each of which have elements with a `title` and `body` ID. Is that right?

Comment: @EvenJohnson: Then that's invalid HTML. Change `title` and `body` to a class instead. You use a given ID only once on a page.

Comment: ...as to your issue, is the `change` function defined globally? If you have it nested inside another function, then the inline `onclick` attribute won't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works if you specify `456` as the argument rather than `this_456` (see: http://jsfiddle.net/aLxTz/).

However, since `<div id="body"/>` is identified by ID (`#body`) it's redundant to look for it inside and other element - it should be unique document-wide. Use the `class=""` attribute if you expect to have several instances of a body `<div/>`, e.g. `<div class="body">...</div>`.

Furthermore, note that the `onclick` handler has the `this` variable set to the context element. Since this is the element in question itself, you could write

```
<div class="main" id="this_456"> ... </div>

$(".main").click(function() {
  $(this).chlidren(".body").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function change(id) {
    $('#this_'+id+ ' > div').find("#body").fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="main" id="this_456" onclick="change(this)">
 <div id="title">some text</div>
 <div id="body">some text as well</div>
</div>

function change(elm) {
   $(elm).children("#body").fadeOut();
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Wzf75/)